# Not able to checkout project from SVN in eclipse - SVN connector library not available

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit, javahl

I am trying to import a new project from SVN repo.
I am using eclipse neon 4.6. I have added SVN plugin via eclipse market place version (image attached).
[image]

I get this error while trying to checkout .

[image]

I could see that a native connector is listed in preference but with error, I am not able to change that.

[image]

Any help will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that JavaHL cannot initialize in your Subversive plug-in. Maybe you installed 64-bit JavaHL connector on 32-bit machine or vice-verse? Anyway, you can follow steps of section [Enable JavaHL in Subversive plug-in for Eclipse](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00145/#subversive) from the article [KB145](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00145/). The article shows how to activate JavaHL in Subversive and Subclipse plugins and the instructions were thoroughly tested.

You can also consider switching from Subversive to Subclipse. I did not see similar problem with Subclipse - it worked right away after installation without issues.